# Competing risk analysis for clustered data

Tags: survival, cox-model, competing-risks

I am conducted a patient-level meta-analysis focusing on survival outcomes. I would like to add a competing risk analysis to the main analysis based on survey methods in R and Stata with Cox proportional hazard analysis called within the survey package.

As a sensitivity analysis, I would like to conduct within the survey package a competing risk analysis. Is it possible?

If not, how can I conduct a competing risk analysis taking into account that data come from different trials (first clustering feature) and some events come from the same patient (second clustering feature)?

Answer (score 0):

It appears after some digging and asking it can be done in R using the `riskregression` package, with a code similar to the following, with `TimeToEvent` being the time to event or censoring, `Event` being exiting the study uneventfully (0), having the first competing event (1), or having the second competing event (2), `Covariate` being the independent variable of interest, `ID` being the patient ID, `Trial` being the study ID, and `Dataset` being the dataset of interest:

```
CSC(Hist(TimeToEvent,Event)~Covariate,cluster(ID)+strata(Trial),data=Dataset)
```